# IntegrityError NOT caught during Unit Test but other DB errors are caught

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, unit-testing

I'm using Python 3.7 and Django 3.0.3

I have a unit test that looks like this:

```
class MaintenenceEndpointTest(APITestCase):
    """Maintenence Endpoint tests
    """
    def test_reset_cost_center_throws_error_if_sales_profile_is_not_in_database(self):
        """Ensure the database throws an error and the endpoint returns 500 if the sales_profile is not in database"""

        response = self.client.post('/maintenance/reset_cost_center/',
                                    data={"cost_center_code": "test_cost_center_code",
                                          "sales_profile": "Fronter SMIA NOT PRESENT"},
                                    format='json',
                                    HTTP_ACCEPT='application/json')

        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, status.HTTP_500_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
```

and inside the Django endpoint code that gets called by the test, I have this:

```
try:
    # Call the Database with an Update using the field(s) chosen by the caller (in kwargs now)
    CostCenter.objects.filter(cost_center_code=cost_center_code).update(**kwargs)

except Exception as e:
    logging.error(
        f' CostCenterUpdateProfileAndRole:post failed with errors.  Failed in updating {cost_center_code} with {kwargs} '
        f'Unexpected error! Error is: [ {e} ]')

    return Response(
        data={'Error': f'Unexpected error! Error is: [ {e} ]',
              }, status=500)

logging.info(
    f' CostCenterUpdateProfileAndRole:post successfully called.  Set the field(s) {kwargs} for cost_center_code {cost_center_code}')

return Response(status=200,
                data={f'Success': f'Provided cost_center_code {cost_center_code} was changed to {kwargs}'})
```

When I run this code under normal circumstances and pass in a non-existing Sales Profile in the JSON, the IntegrityError is ALWAYS caught by the try/except and it passes back the 500.

When I run the Unit Test the IntegrityError is NEVER caught by the try/except and the code under test returns the 200.

Later, after the code I'm testing has finished running, the IntegrityError shows up as having been thrown during the test, as well as the test failing because 200 != 500

The error:

```
File "/Users/xxx.xxxxxxxxx/Documents/workspace/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py", line 348, in check_constraints
    bad_value, referenced_table_name, referenced_column_name
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: The row in table 'cost_center' with primary key 'test_cost_center_code' has an invalid foreign key: cost_center.sales_profile_id contains a value 'Fronter SMIA NOT PRESENT' that does not have a corresponding value in sales_profile.sales_profile_name.
```

I tested by purposefully causing a different Database error and that one WAS caught by the Unit Test every time.

What is happening with IntegrityError such that it is NOT caught by the code under test during the runtime of that code - thus causing my test to fail?

And, obviously - what can I do to get my test to run successfully and get that IntegrityError caught by my tested code where it should be?